# Create table in Javascript with data is object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, row

Data has format object:

```
[
  {
    "key": "key1",
    "value": [
      {
        "code": "AVF",
        "data": [
          [0,"AVF"],
          [1,4.7],
          [2,4.1],
          [3,4.4],
          [10,4.4],
          [20,4.4],
          [19,71524],
          [21,4.7],
          [22,4.4],
          [8,4.6],
          [9,15543],
          [6,4.5],
          [7,34878],
          [4,4.4]
        ]
      },
      {
        "code": "BCE",
        "data": [
          [0,"BCE"],
          [1,10.7],
          [2,9.3],
          [3,10],
          [10,10],
          [20,10],
          [19,2275],
          [21,10.3],
          [22, 10],
          [8,10.1],
          [9,638],
          [6,10],
          [7,2555],
          [4,9.9],
          [5,1935]
        ]
      }
    ],
    "duration": 5
  },
  {
    "key": "key2",
    "value": [
      {
        "code": "AVEF",
        "data": [
          [0,"AVE"],
          [1,5.7],
          [2,4.1],
          [3,4.4],
          [10,4.4],
          [20,4.4],
          [19,7124],
          [21,4.7],
          [22,4.4],
          [8,4.6],
          [9,18543],
          [6,4.0],
          [7,3678],
          [4,1.4]
        ]
      },
      {
        "code": "CTG",
        "data": [
          [0,"CTG"],
          [1,10.7],
          [2,9.3],
          [3,10],
          [10,4],
          [20,10],
          [19,2275],
          [21,20.3],
          [22, 10],
          [8,10.1],
          [9,638],
          [6,10],
          [7,2555],
          [4,9.9],
          [5,1935]
        ]
      }
    ],
    "duration": 5
  }
]
```

I want to create table:

[image]

Table has 24 columns, serial of column like value of first element ([5,1935] with first element is 5). I want the elements show with serial column. If column not exist then it is empty.

My js:

```
/*
var g_arrData = 
[{"co":"AAM", "ce":14.3, "fl":12.5, "re":13.4, "cl": 13.3}
,{"co":"ABT", "ce":54.5, "fl":47.5, "re":51, "cl": 51.5}
,{"co":"ACL", "ce":10.3, "fl":9.1, "re":9.7, "cl": 10.3}
]
*/


// global
function $$(id) {return document.getElementById(id);}

function Stock4G(DivID, arrData)
{
    this.m_DivID = DivID;
    this.m_arrData = arrData;
    var bp1 = '', bp1Data = '', mp = '', mpData = '', ceData = '', flData = '', reData = '';
    // bat dau
    this.Init = function()
    {
        var HTML = ''
        HTML += '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">';
        HTML += '<table id="FPTSQuote" class="tqt" style="border: 3px solid #505050;" border="1" bordercolor="#505050" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" >';
        HTML += '<tr height="18"><th class="hbrb" rowspan="2" id="te">Mã CK</th><th class="hg_b" rowspan="2">Trần</th><th class="hg_b" rowspan="2">Sàn</th><th class="hgrb" rowspan="2">TC</th><th class="hbr_" colspan="6">Dư mua</th><th class="hg_b" rowspan="2">Giá<br>khớp</th><th class="hg_b" rowspan="2">KL<br>khớp</th><th class="hgrb" rowspan="2">+/-</th><th class="hbr_" colspan="6">Dư bán</th><th class="hg_b" rowspan="2">Tổng<br>KL</th><th class="hg_b" rowspan="2" style="display:none">Trung<br>bình</th><th class="hg_b" rowspan="2">Mở<br>cửa</th><th class="hg_b" rowspan="2">Cao<br>nhất</th><th class="hg_b" rowspan="2">Thấp<br>nhất</th><th class="hg_b" rowspan="2">NN<br>mua</th><th class="hg_b" rowspan="2" style="display:none">NN<br>bán</th></tr>';
        HTML += '<tr height="18"><th class="hb_b">Giá 3</th><th class="hb_b">KL 3</th><th class="hb_b">Giá 2</th><th class="hb_b">KL 2</th><th class="hb_b">Giá 1</th><th class="hbrb">KL 1</th><th class="hb_b">Giá 1</th><th class="hb_b">KL 1</th><th class="hb_b">Giá 2</th><th class="hb_b">KL 2</th><th class="hb_b">Giá 3</th><th class="hbrb">KL3</th></tr>'
        $$(DivID).innerHTML = HTML;

        $.each(arrData, function (indexrow, value) {
            bp1 = '', bp1Data = '', mp = '', mpData = '', ceData = '', flData = '', reData = '';
            if (indexrow != 'code') {
                $.each(value, function (indexvalue, arrayData) {
                    HTML += '<tr>';
                    for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
                        HTML += '<td></td>';
                    }
                    HTML += '</tr>';
                    $$(DivID).innerHTML = HTML;
                   if (jQuery.type(arrayData) != 'string') {

                       $.each(arrayData, function (indexarrayData, arDatachild) {

                           if (arDatachild[0] == 0) {
                               //alert()
                               //= arDatachild[1];
                               document.getElementById('FPTSQuote').rows[indexrow + 2].cells[0].innerHTML = arDatachild[1];
                           document.getElementById('FPTSQuote').rows[indexrow + 2].cells[0].className = "ccc";
                               //HTML += '<td class="ccc">' + arDatachild[1] + '</td>';
                            }
                           else {
                               //if (arDatachild[1] == 0) {
                               //    HTML += '<td class=' + GetColor(arDatachild[1], arDatachild[0]) + '></td>';
                               //}
                               //else {
                               //    HTML += '<td class=' + GetColor(arDatachild[1], arDatachild[0]) + '>' + arDatachild[1] + '</td>';
                               //}

                            }
                        })
                    }
                })
            }
        })
        //$("#FPTSQuote td:contains('Mã')").html('YourTextToReplace');
        //console.log(document.getElementById('FPTSQuote').rows[0].cells[0])
        //document.getElementById('FPTSQuote').rows[0].cells[0].innerHTML = "dsfasd";
        HTML += '</table>'
        $$(this.m_DivID).innerHTML = HTML;
        //document.getElementById('FPTSQuote').rows[0].cells[0].innerHTML = "dsfasd";
    }

    function GetColor(v, index)
    {
        if (index == '1') { ceData = v; return 'g_c'; }
        else if (index == '2') { flData = v; return 'g_f'; }
        else if (index == '3') { reData = v; return 'grr'; }
        else if (index == '4' || index == '6' || index == '13' || index == '15') {
            if (v == ceData) return bp3 = 'b_c';
            if (v == flData) return bp3 = 'b_f';
            if (v == reData) return bp3 = 'b_r';
            if (v < reData) return bp3 = 'b_d';
            if (v > reData) return bp3 = 'b_u';
        }
        else if (index == '5' || index == '7' || index == '14' || index == '16') { return bp3; }
        else if (index == '8' || index == '17') {
            bp1Data = v;
            if (v == ceData) return 'b_c';
            if (v == flData) return 'b_f';
            if (v == reData) return 'b_r';
            if (v < reData) return 'b_d';
            if (v > reData) return 'b_u';
        }
        else if (index == '9' || index == '18') {
            if (bp1Data == ceData) return 'brc';
            if (bp1Data == flData) return 'brf';
            if (bp1Data == reData) return 'brr';
            if (bp1Data < reData) return 'brd';
            if (bp1Data > reData) return 'bru';;
        }
        else if (index == '10') {
            mpData = v;
            if (v == ceData) return mp = 'g_c';
            if (v == flData) return mp = 'g_f';
            if (v == reData) return mp = 'g_r';
            if (v < reData) return mp = 'g_d';
            if (v > reData) return mp = 'g_u';
        }
        else if (index == '11') { return mp; }
        else if (index == '12') {
            if (mpData == '0') { return 'gr_'; }
            else {
                if (v == ceData) return 'grc';
                if (v==flData) return 'grf';
                if (v== reData) return 'grr';
                if (v < reData) return 'grd';
                if (v>RereData) return 'gru';
            }
        }
        else if (index == '20' || index == '21' || index == '22') {
            if (v == ceData) return 'g_c';
            if (v == flData) return 'g_f';
            if (v == reData) return 'g_r';
            if (v < reData) return 'g_d';
            if (v > reData) return 'g_u';
        }
        else { return 'g__'; }
    }
    // entry point
    this.Init();
}


window.onload = function()
{
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //var refreshId = setInterval(
        //function() {
            var key = ['key1', 'key2'];
            $.each(key, function (indext, itemData) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "api/Quote/" + itemData + "",
                    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
                    success: function (data) {
                        var g_Stock4G = new Stock4G('divBody', data)

                    }
                });
            })
        //}
        //}, 5000);
    });
}
```

I have a idea: create row with columns empty,after change column with

```
document.getElementById('FPTSQuote').rows[indexrow + 2].cells[0].innerHTML = arDatachild[1];
                               document.getElementById('FPTSQuote').rows[indexrow + 2].cells[0].className = "ccc";
```

but it don't work. I tried set two line code bellow in under line code:

```
HTML += '</table>'
        $$(this.m_DivID).innerHTML = HTML;
```

then it works. I don't understand.
Help me, please!